# ClassNotFoundException when importing record from other namespace

Tags: clojure, namespaces, leiningen

I have following files:

**src/my_proj/myns.clj**:

```
(ns my-proj.myns)
(defrecord MyRecord  [a b c])
```

**test/my_proj/myns_test.clj**:

```
(ns my-proj.myns-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
        [my-proj.myns :refer :all])
  (:import [my-proj.myns MyRecord]))

(def my-rec (MyRecord. "A" "B" "C"))

(deftest my-test
  (testing "test"
    (is (:a my-rec))))
```

When I run :

```
lein test
```

I get a ClassNotFoundException :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my-proj.myns.MyRecord
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.findClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are importing, you'll need to change hyphens to underscores

```
user=> (ns sad-hyphen)
nil
sad-hyphen=> (defrecord MyRecord [a b c])
sad_hyphen.MyRecord
sad-hyphen=> (ns foo)
nil
foo=> (import '(sad-hyphen MyRecord))
ClassNotFoundException sad-hyphen.MyRecord ... 
foo=> (import '(sad_hyphen MyRecord))
sad_hyphen.MyRecord
```

However, there is not generally a need to import a record, just use the `->MyRecord` and `map->MyRecord` constructors (brought into your namespace via require/refer).

Comment: Thanks, this moved me bit further. But still I have problem with lein. In REPL it is working as you described. But when running lein test I still get ClassNotFoundException. When using map->MyRecordMyRecord (which works fine in REPL), I'm getting  "Unable to resolve symbol: map->MyRecordMyRecord in this context, compiling:(my_proj/myns_test.clj:6:13)", when running lein test.

Comment: @ViktorK. It would just be `map->MyRecord` not `map->MyRecordMyRecord` for the constructor that takes a map argument.

Comment: thanks, I was probably too tired yesterday when I typed that :)