# extend-protocol when both defrecord and protocol are in another namespace

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to use extend-protocol to extend a protocol and a record from different namespaces, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Syntax error compiling at (src/http_client/client_mixed.clj:10:1).
No such var: either/Right
```

Here is the code:

```clj
(ns http-client.client-mixed
  (:require [cats.core :as m]
            [cats.monad.either :as either]
            [fmnoise.flow :as f]))

(extend-protocol f/Flow
  either/Right
  (?ok [this f] (f (m/extract this)))
  (?err [this _] (m/extract this))
  (?throw [this] (m/extract this))

  either/Left
  (?ok [this _] (m/extract this))
  (?err [this f] (f (ex-info "Either.Left" (m/extract this))))
  (?throw [this] (throw (ex-info "Either.Left" (m/extract this)))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A defrecord must be imported as a regular Java class. So, this would be the correct code:

```clj
(ns http-client.client-mixed
  (:require [cats.core :as m]
            [cats.monad.either :as either]
            [fmnoise.flow :as f])
  (:import (cats.monad.either Left Right)))

(extend-protocol f/Flow
  Right
  (?ok [this f] (f (m/extract this)))
  (?err [this _] (m/extract this))
  (?throw [this] (m/extract this))

  Left
  (?ok [this _] (m/extract this))
  (?err [this f] (f (ex-info "Either.Left" (m/extract this))))
  (?throw [this] (throw (ex-info "Either.Left" (m/extract this)))))
```

Comment: One caveat worth noting is that if the namespace you are importing has hyphens in the name, these need to be replaced with underscores in the :import clause, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23420084/726181